# java.util.zip.Deflater and GWT

Tags: java, gwt, zip

Is `java.util.zip.Deflater` available in GWT 2.6.0? Do I need to do anything special to be able to use it?

I get this error message currently when trying to compile as part of running Super Dev Mode:

```
[ERROR] Line 238: No source code is available for type java.util.zip.Deflater; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Comment: Are you really trying to zip/unzip files **in the browser**?

Comment: Yes. I am writing a PNG using the bytes from a LibGDX Pixmap representation of a game screen, and then uploading it to a web service. JavaScript isn't just for form validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `java.util.zip.Deflater` at client side in GWT application because GWT is unable to compile it into JavaScript.

Read more about [GWT library emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util)